# SQL Complex number constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

Hello i am using PostegreSQL and i want to constrain a certain number(tax ID number) to obey the following rules:

- 9 Digits
- The last digit (z) is calculated according to:

x = 8th * 2 + 7th * 3 + 6th * 4 + 5th * 5 + 4th * 6 + 3rd * 7 + 2nd * 8 + 1st + 9

```
y = x % 11  
if (y == 0 || x == 1) z = 0;
else z = 11 - y
```

Is this possible in sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible although cumbersome.  It looks something like this:

```
check ((col regexp_matches '^[0-9]{9}$) and
       (case when (substring(col, 1, 1) * 9 + substring(col, 2, 1) * 8 + substring(col, 3, 1) * 7 +
                   substring(col, 4, 1) * 6 + substring(col, 5, 1) * 5 + substring(col, 6, 1) * 4 +
                   substring(col, 7, 1) * 3 + substring(col, 8, 1) * 2 
                  ) % 11 = 0 or
                  (substring(col, 1, 1) * 9 + substring(col, 2, 1) * 8 + substring(col, 3, 1) * 7 +
                   substring(col, 4, 1) * 6 + substring(col, 5, 1) * 5 + substring(col, 6, 1) * 4 +
                   substring(col, 7, 1) * 3 + substring(col, 8, 1) * 2 
                  ) = 1
             then 0
             else 11 -
                  ((substring(col, 1, 1) * 9 + substring(col, 2, 1) * 8 + substring(col, 3, 1) * 7 +
                    substring(col, 4, 1) * 6 + substring(col, 5, 1) * 5 + substring(col, 6, 1) * 4 +
                    substring(col, 7, 1) * 3 + substring(col, 8, 1) * 2 
                   ) % 11
                  )
        end) = substring(col, 9, 1) + 0
    )
```

Personally, I would encapsulate it in a function and use the function instead.

Comment: Why not a PL/pgSQL function (which would be close to a transliteration of the English requirements) instead of that unpleasant pile of `substring`s?

Comment: this answer seems to work nicely, thank you! is it possible to avoid the excessive lines of code by storing the repeated operations in a variable? I'm sorry my sql knowledge is a bit rust but i rembember storing some values

Comment: PL/pgSQL function would be better but that would force me to use the function when i needed to add a new value and not a flexible sql query right? or could i just create a trigger/constraint  to call "Select function()" and verify it returning true?

Comment: @user2820208 . . . You can do the latter.  You can call the function in the `check` constraint and see that it returns what you need.

Comment: Well i'll keep this solution for now, since it is working and it has the compatibility factor on since its all sql. Thank you for your answer.